# Saving and Remembering In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

How do I hide an iAd banner once a non-consumable "Remove Ads" In-App Purchase has been made? I'm not quite sure how to do that or where to do that, according to [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) tutorial.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *PokeABowlAd;


@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#define SHOW_ADS_KEY @"Show Ads Key"
#define k_Save @"Saveitem"


#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>


@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize viewWeb;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];


NSString *fullURL = @"https://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
viewWeb.scalesPageToFit = YES;
viewWeb.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
// Wait for location callbacks
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}

-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"iitc" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
}



- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
}


- (IBAction)PokeABowlAd:(id)sender {
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]  isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show ads
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.pokeabowl.com/"]];
} else {
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
}
NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]);

}

- (void)viewWillAppear {
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show ads
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;

} else {
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
}
NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]);
}


@end
```

MasterViewController.m:

```
    #import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController () {
NSArray *_products;
NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];

self.title = @"Settings";

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self reload];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

_priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(restoreTapped:)];

}

- (void)restoreTapped:(id)sender {
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
[_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

}

- (void)reload {
_products = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        _products = products;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return _products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
} else {
    UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
    [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
}

return cell;
}

- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}

@end
```

IAPHelper.h:

```
    #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>


UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification;

typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);

@interface IAPHelper : NSObject

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers;
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product;
- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *PokeABowlAd;

@end
```

IAPHelper.m:

```
    #define SHOW_ADS_KEY @"Show Ads Key"

// 1
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification = @"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";

// 2
@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@end

// 3
@implementation IAPHelper {
SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;

NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;
}




- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    // Store product identifiers
    _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

    // Check for previously purchased products
    _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     boolForKey:productIdentifier];
        if (productPurchased) {
            [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            // NEW CODE
            if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Ads"]){
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }
            // NEW CODE ^^

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
    }

    // Add self as transaction observer
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
}
return self;
}


- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {


// 1
_completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

// 2
_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];

}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
_productsRequest = nil;

NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
    NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
          skProduct.productIdentifier,
          skProduct.localizedTitle,
          skProduct.price.floatValue);
}

_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
_completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
_productsRequest = nil;

_completionHandler(NO, nil);
_completionHandler = nil;

}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionOBserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
    }
};
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
{
    NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
}

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

[_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];

}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

@end
```

RageIAPHelper.h

```
    #import "IAPHelper.h"

@interface RageIAPHelper : IAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

RageIAPHelper.m

```
    #import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation RageIAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
static dispatch_once_t once;
static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                  @“com.GPS.iapra",
                                  @"com.GPS.iapb”,
                                  nil];
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
});
return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should NSUserDefaults.

Put at the top of both .m files:

```
#define SHOW_ADS_KEY @"Show Ads Key"
```

When the user has purchased the IAP you do this (in IAP.m):

```
- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    // Store product identifiers
    _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

    // Check for previously purchased products
    _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     boolForKey:productIdentifier];
        if (productPurchased) {
            [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
// NEW CODE
if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.GPS.iapra"]){
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
// NEW CODE ^^

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
    }

    // Add self as transaction observer
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

}
```

For the ad code (in VC.m):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear { 
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
      // Code to show ads
      PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;

   } else {
      PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
   }
NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]); 
}
```

Now modify completeTransaction:

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.GPS.iapra"]){
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and tried this and couldn't get it to work. I guess maybe I'm not putting this code in the right place. I've finished the tutorial i mentioned above, but it doesn't explain saving/unlocking in-app purchases.

Comment: If this doesn't work then you are putting it in the wrong place. Maybe show your code?

Comment: Well you didn't post the code with your ads so I can't see if that is right but I modified your buyButtonTapped in my answer to show what it should look like.

Comment: You can put this wherever the user actually buys the IAP

Comment: I dont know why, but it just doesnt seem to be working. Am I naming everything wrong?

Comment: Ok I added the code for the ads. Everything should work now. If you have already "purchased" the IAP you should reset the content and settings in your simulator.

Comment: @Creagen, ok I made it so that it should work right from the beginning

Comment: Also you better be using your actual product identifier

Comment: Are you using the correct product identifier? And are you actually calling initWithProductIdentifiers somewhere?

Comment: I have copy and pasted the code exactly as you said and in the proper files. As for the product identifier, where would i add that? I have two productId's in a file called RAGEIAPHelper.m - It looks like this: https://github.com/swapgo20/iOS-In-App-Purchase/blob/master/In%20App%20Purchase/RageIAPHelper.m

Comment: You need to create a non-consumable in iTunes Connect and put that product id in the code (where I have @"Ads" as a placeholder). I have answered your question (so please select it) but you have to do the rest.

Comment: I'm obviously really close, and I have the IAP purchase ID. It is com.GPS.iapra and i put it in the @Ads and it still does not hide ads.

Comment: Are you calling the initWithProductIdentifiers method? Do you see the previous purchases being printed by the NSLog in initWithProductIdentifiers?

Comment: In my xcode log it says I have previously purchased the remove ads and have not purchased the bookmarks tool. But it still doesnt not remove the banner. In my ViewController.h file i have @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *PokeABowlAd;

Comment: Do you have more code for your ad than [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.pokeabowl.com/"]];
? If not put an NSLog right before it and print the value of the NSUserDefaults element.

Comment: No more code, just the @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *PokeABowlAd; in ViewController.h

Comment: Are you not adding it programmatically?

Comment: Look at the two new lines I added in my second block of code (the lines with .hidden). Try making that change.

Comment: So change isEqualToString:@"Ads"]){ - isEqualToString:@"com.GPS.iapra"]){ and copy and paste the (id)initWithProductIdentifiers code in IAPHelper.m and add the ibaction code in VC.m and it should work?

Comment: The third part should be different. I made one more change.

Comment: So do the NSLog thing and tell me what it prints for the value of the NSUserDefaults

Comment: I believe it just prints 2015-08-12 11:56:23.906 GPS[264:8828] Previously purchased: com.GPS.iapra
2015-08-12 11:56:23.907 GPS[264:8828] Not purchased: com.GPS.iapb

Comment: No that's not what I meant. Add the NSLog line I added above in viewWIllAppear and tell me what it prints.

Comment: When I run it nothing else comes up.

Comment: Try it one more time with the change I added before the %@

Comment: Still nothing. Do I have to change Show Ads to something else?

Comment: But it says Show Ads?:  right? See the update I have made with the new define statement. Try that.

Comment: I get "incompatible pointer types sending uiimage to parameter of type nsstring"

Comment: Oh I think it was because it said "No" instead of @"No" in the IAP.m

Comment: I changed the "No" to @"No" but i still get the error message. Any way I can share this project with you so you can get a better idea? I feel as if I'm only missing something simple.

Comment: In your simulator reset content and settings and try it again, I think it will work.

Comment: In the IAP.m file. If you want me to add you to my shared folder on dropbox you can check out the project as it is now.

Comment: Is it this line: [self     provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.produc    tIdentifier];

Comment: You have that random space between product and tIdentifier

Comment: The space seems to just be in the code on the forum, not in the project.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey:_PokeABowlAd];

Comment: Well obviously that's wrong. The Key is supposed to be the one I made in the #define statement.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey:Show Ads Key];
now i just get use of undeclared identifier Show

Comment: And have you put the #define statement at the top of the .m file?

Comment: Yes now I dont have the error message. but I still have the ad :(

Comment: And what does that NSLog line print now?

Comment: The same purchased and not purchased. Nothing more

Comment: And I am still not talking about that NSLog

Comment: I just edited my question and updated every file to exactly how it is now. Maybe you'll catch something I'm doing wrong. I feel like I've tried a lot of things but it must be something so simple.

Comment: Please tell me what the NSLogs in the viewWillAppear are saying.

Comment: You never changed this line of code:             if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Ads"]){

Comment: It should be @“com.GPS.iapra" instead of @"Ads"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where to see or find that information. I've been googling to try and find how to find that information so that I don't bother you with that nonsense but I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: What? Just look in the console. It should print something when the view controller appears. What is so confusing?

Comment: All it prints is 2015-08-12 13:28:27.199 GPS[43646:2786146] Not purchased: com.GPS.iapra
2015-08-12 13:28:27.200 GPS[43646:2786146] Not purchased: com.GPS.iapb and I changed the line of code: if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Ads"]){

Comment: Move the contents of viewWillAppear to viewDidLoad and tell me if you are able to see the results of the NSLog

Comment: OMG, OK, check this out... it finally ran a NSLog and spat out 2015-08-12 13:34:16.531 GPS[494:32807] Shows ads?: No      and the ad was not there. But get THIS... when I deleted the app, and re-installed it, the ad was back, which is normal, thats good, but when I made a succesful purchase and went back to my main view controller, the ad was not remove BUT when i quit the app and reopened it, the ad was gone and stays gone. like it rememebers NOW that I've purchased it, but not right after it is purchased. Any thoughts??

Comment: Ok now change the completeTransaction method. View the latest change above.

Comment: How and where do you mean?

Comment: That didn't seem to do it. I placed a new purchase and the ad was not removed. It still only disappears once you quit the app and open it again.

Comment: Ok so try recreating the viewWillAppear method

Comment: I still have this in the VC.m file:  - (void)viewWillAppear {
    if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
        // Code to show ads
        _PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;
        
    } else {
        _PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]);
}

Comment: Are you seeing the ad in MasterVC or just in VC?

Comment: Just the View Controller file

Comment: After you buy the IAP are you seeing the Show Ad?: NSLog result in the VC?

Comment: I am only seeing the NSLog for Show Ads on Launch

Comment: So now all you have to do is call the code that is located in the viewWillAppear / viewDidLoad methods once you return to your VC after purchasing the IAP. How you do that is up to you. If you need help with that I would suggest asking a new question since this comment thread is getting very long. I'd appreciate if you upvote my answer and choose it as the correct answer since I've helped you get this working.

Comment: Alright...and let's say I want to handle the same thing for a different IAP, would I basically just do the same thing again?

Comment: You should be able to now

Comment: Awesome. I think I'll start a new question for 'return to VC after purchasing the IAP' question. Thank you so much for your help. I don't know who you are, but you are awesome! Hopefully I can return the favor one day.

Comment: Just incase - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975790/saving-changes-after-in-app-purchase-has-been-purchased :) Thank you!

Comment: I'll see if I can help you out later. I'd appreciate if you download my game Draw Me That... There's a link in my profile. Glad I was helpful!

Comment: That would be awesome. Thank you! I'll be sure to download your game and leave a review. The review will come from BlackHatTriStar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86842/discussion-between-wmios-and-creagen).