# Saving Changes After In-App Purchase Has Been Purchased

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have an In-App Purchase in my app for removing an ad banner and when I made a successful purchase and went back to my main view controller, the ad was not removed BUT when i quit the app and reopen it, the ad is gone and stays gone. Almost like it remembers that I've purchased the remove ads IAP on the next load, but not right after it is purchased. A very smart person told me i need to do this:

> So now all you have to do is call the code that is located in the
>   viewWillAppear / viewDidLoad methods once you return to your VC after
>   purchasing the IAP. How you do that is up to you. If you need help
>   with that I would suggest asking a new question since this comment
>   thread is getting very long. I'd appreciate if you upvote my answer
>   and choose it as the correct answer since I've helped you get this
>   working.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thank you!

Here is a screenshot of my Master View Controller:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *PokeABowlAd;


@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#define SHOW_ADS_KEY @"Show Ads Key"
#define k_Save @"Saveitem"


#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>


@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize viewWeb;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];


NSString *fullURL = @"https://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
viewWeb.scalesPageToFit = YES;
viewWeb.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
// Wait for location callbacks
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}

-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"iitc" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
}



- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
}


- (IBAction)PokeABowlAd:(id)sender {
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]  isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show ads
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.pokeabowl.com/"]];
} else {
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
}
NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]);

}

- (void)viewWillAppear {
if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY] isEqualToString: @"No"]){ // NEW CODE
    // Code to show ads
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = NO;

} else {
    _PokeABowlAd.hidden = YES;
}
NSLog(@"Shows ads?: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY]);
}


@end
```

MasterViewController.m:

```
    #import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController () {
NSArray *_products;
NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];

self.title = @"Settings";

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self reload];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

_priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(restoreTapped:)];

}

- (void)restoreTapped:(id)sender {
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
[_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

}

- (void)reload {
_products = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        _products = products;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return _products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
} else {
    UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
    [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
}

return cell;
}

- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}

@end
```

IAPHelper.h:

```
    #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>


UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification;

typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);

@interface IAPHelper : NSObject

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers;
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product;
- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *PokeABowlAd;

@end
```

IAPHelper.m:

```
    #define SHOW_ADS_KEY @"Show Ads Key"

// 1
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification = @"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";

// 2
@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@end

// 3
@implementation IAPHelper {
SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;

NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;
}




- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    // Store product identifiers
    _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

    // Check for previously purchased products
    _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     boolForKey:productIdentifier];
        if (productPurchased) {
            [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            // NEW CODE
            if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Ads"]){
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }
            // NEW CODE ^^

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
    }

    // Add self as transaction observer
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
}
return self;
}


- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {


// 1
_completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

// 2
_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];

}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
_productsRequest = nil;

NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
    NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
          skProduct.productIdentifier,
          skProduct.localizedTitle,
          skProduct.price.floatValue);
}

_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
_completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
_productsRequest = nil;

_completionHandler(NO, nil);
_completionHandler = nil;

}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionOBserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
    }
};
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
{
    NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
}

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

[_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];

}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

@end
```

RageIAPHelper.h

```
    #import "IAPHelper.h"

@interface RageIAPHelper : IAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

RageIAPHelper.m

```
    #import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation RageIAPHelper

+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
static dispatch_once_t once;
static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                  @“com.GPS.iapra",
                                  @"com.GPS.iapb”,
                                  nil];
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
});
return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Comment: Post your method, where you tell your ad banner to show up or hide.

Comment: It sounds like your ad doesn't check for the purchase in viewWillAppear.  You'll need to post your code to say for sure.

Comment: Do you purchase the IAP in the VC or in MasterVC? If it's in MasterVC, try copying and pasting the viewWillAppear method from VC to MasterVC.

Comment: I make the purchase in the MasterVC. I'll try adding it to MVC now...That  didn't seem to work :/

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the MasterVC? Also, are you Creagen like the actor Creagen Dow?

Comment: I have edited my question to show a screenshot of my MVC and my storyboard. Also, yes I am. lol :)

Comment: @Creagen, check out my answer below. Also, that's awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think what's happening is that it isn't recognizing your purchase until the `initWithProductIdentifers` method in IAP.m is being called (which only happens when you load the application).

So in IAP.m try modifying:

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

To:

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

        // NEW CODE
            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Ads"]){
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"No" forKey:SHOW_ADS_KEY];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }
        // NEW CODE ^^

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

Also, I think the reason your viewWillAppear isn't getting called is because it looks like you have two NavigationControllers in your storyboard. Try deleting the second one (the one between VC and MasterVC). If you do both of these that should make it work.

Comment: I just gave that a shot and it didn't seem to remove the ad :/

Comment: You removed the second NavigationController? Did the NSLog in the viewWillAppear go off?

Comment: Found the problem! Everything you said was needed, the only thing I changed to make it work is - (void)viewWillAppear to - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated :D You are a genius! Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you

Comment: Oh yeah that would do it haha!

Comment: It might be a lot to ask, but I'd really appreciate if you tweeted about Draw Me That (and I'll keep helping you out with your app on SO)! Glad you finally got it all working!

Comment: I'll definitely tweet it out! It will be coming from @CreagenDow on Twitter. Be sure to give me a follow and I'll follow you back. Thank you for all the help, I'll probably need some more guidance in the future, hopefully later rather than sooner :p Add me on Facebook and we'll keep in touch or add me on SO. I haven't fully explored how this site works, yet. lol

Comment: @Creagen, I don't have a twitter yet but when I do (planning on getting one soon) I'll definitely follow you. I'll add you on Facebook.